# How to connect form data on app to other page?

Tags: android, ios, api, android-studio

Okay so I’m trying to build a simple confirmation page and failing lol. Please help.

All the app is supposed to do is take a user to a form, and they fill it in. Go to a loading page (optional) , then a confirmation page.

Example:
Form requesting for name,address and color of item,and email address.

Then confirmation page says “Thank you [name] your order for a [color] shirt will be on your way. Check out your email for further details.

Note:
I don’t need to personally get the information typed in, I’m just starting out and would like to know how to do this first .

Comment: See DialogFragment

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to store the form data at some variables and inject those variables when you construct the confirmation screen